# iTerm 2 style fullscreen for chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am using yosemite

iTerm 2 allows me to full screen without switching to new space and preserves cmd + tab application switching via keyboard.

when i press cmd + shift + f in chrome it switches to a new space, and disables switching to chrome via cmd + tab - is it possible to full screen chrome without switching to new space and keeping cmd + tab functionality in tact (just like iterm)?

[image]

Notice my laptop screen goes dark when chrome is in full screen, whereas with iTerm, I can full screen and have access to both monitors

[image]

Comment: Do you have "Displays have separate Spaces" on?

Comment: no i do not, just 'group windows by application'